# Изменить цвет текста в js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть код:

```
function loadcart() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/include/loadcart.php",
    dataType: "html",
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
      if (data == "0") {
        $("#block-basket > a").html("test");
      } else {
        $("#block-basket > a").html(data);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Как изменить цвет слова `test` на белый?

Comment: *Есть код в js* - на jquery

Answer (score 6):

Топорно

```
$("#block-basket > a").html('<span style="color:white">test</span>');
```

Назначить `span` стиль.

```
$("#block-basket > a").html('<span class="white-text">test</span>');
```

В CSS

```
.white-text{
  color:white;
}
```

Также можно поменять CSS у самого тега `<a>`, если надо.

```
$('#block-basket > a').css({"color":"white"}).html("Test");
```